# How to Block PicScout Bot

Tags: bots

I would like to block PicScout Web Robot from accessing my site. I have read that it does not behave like a "good" robot should, so how should I go about doing this?

*Please Note:* I use a hosted CMS. I do not have access to server side scripts. I do not mind answers that include server side scripts but I am looking specifically for a non-server side way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PicScout is a copyright verification robot, not a search engine spider.  So it's perhaps understandable that they don't behave like "good" robots.  They're more like a private security firm than anything else.  Also note that there is no requirement on the Internet that they do so: robots.txt is a convention, not a rule.

There are people who've done research on how to stop or slow down PicScout.   A simple Google search will go a long way.  [This](http://rankexploits.com/protect/2011/12/four-steps-to-slow-down-image-scrapers/) is one slightly out-of-date example.  However, all of the recommendations are .htaccess configuration tweaks, which it sounds like you might not have access to.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and yeah I do not have access to `.htaccess` - I understand the point of PicScout however it uses up (sometimes massive amounts of) bandwidth. I do not have unlimited bandwidth and frankly reading about some of the techniques PicScout is using it is immoral and against terms of service for my website (and many other websites).

Comment: I totally understand your position, I didn't mean to defend PicScout either, and I'm also sure that Stack Overflow isn't really the right place for a debate over whether what PicScout is doing is fair or legit.  I just wanted to put some context around why they don't behave like "good" robots.

Without access to .htaccess or something lower level (ip-tables, etc) you're probably out of luck on your own.  However, you might consider checking with the hosted CMS to see if they have a solution for throttling excessive users of your bandwidth.

Comment: I agree that S.O. isn't the place to debate this but I bet it would be interesting debate => Thanks for your info and I will check with my CMS.

Answer (score -2):

Add to robots.txt

```
# Block PicScout Crawler from crawling site 
User-agent: PicScout
Disallow: /
```

Comment: This won't work, [PicScout doesn't respect robots.txt](https://incredibill.blogspot.com/2006/11/hunting-picscout-copyright-crawler.html#Blog1:~:text=refusal%20to%20honor%20robots.txt%20files).